# how to find OAuth client id? Suspicious activity

Tags: google-oauth

I reviewed a suspicious activity in Google activity web page. 
The authorized app seems to be 800521135851.apps.googleusercontent.com & IP 130.211.197.142 (belongs to Google Cloud)

I read that the number 800521135851 is a unique client ID generated in the API Google Console.

How can I find out which app/service is responsible for this activity, in order to make sure the account was not breached? :)

Thank you

Comment: If this is all on google cloud you could probably use stackdriver

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Cloud Platform console you can visit the "APIs & Services" tab and select "Credentials" there. You'll find a list of authorized clients/applications with a descriptive name.